# Synthesis of para-chloroanisole using diazotisation followed by chlorination with aluminium chloride

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, aromatic-compounds, halides, ethers

Is this a legitimate reaction scheme to synthesise *para*-chloroanisole from benzene and methanol as the only organic reactants?

$$\ce{C6H6 -> HNO3/H2SO4 -> H2/Pd -> HONO/{Ethanol}\\ -> {Methoxide}/THF -> Cl2/AlCl3}$$

I think this would make *ortho*-chloroanisole (minor product) and *para*-chloroanisole (major product).

The methoxide would be generated by:
$$\ce{{Methanol} -> NaH -> {Methoxide}}$$

Comment: Yeah, that works. For posteriority: [related question of OP’s](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/68048).